# External img src is corrupted n Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

$("#imgProduct").attr("src", "C:\Users\SP006\Downloads\Phone.png");

The above code seems to be working in [IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6tNs.png) but is corrupted in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPqtY.png).

I've tried setting the src in html and works fine in IE but not in Chrome. I've cleared the cache but the image is still corrupted in Chrome.

The image is not corrupted in Chrome only when I add the image in the project resources. But the image is dynamic and I only access it through a server folder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note \ characters need to be escaped when used in strings, eg \\ also Chrome and modern browsers do you not allow local resources (from the users harddrive for instance) to be loaded to an online web page. You should be seeing an error in the javascript console (dev tools F12 on most browsers)

Comment: based on my understanding, dont use absolute path for image.